# Run cleanup in library when main program exits

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

I have a small library written in C which controls a hardware device. The library uses pthreads -- it starts a thread which is in charge of interacting with the hardware device.

In some use cases (but not always) this small library may be used from a Java application (vía JNI). When the Java application calls `System.exit()`, all threads are terminated and the library doesn't get a chance to ensure that the hardware device is left in an "idle" state.

Is it possible for the library to setup a cleanup function that will be called when the main program exits, or when the thread is terminated? Something conceptually similar to `atexit` (but I know that atexit [should not be called from a shared library](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82246)).

Comment: Provide a function that does the cleanup work.  Make it the responsibility of the code using your library to call it at the correct time.

Comment: Create a Java class through which your library is accessed. Have the class's destructor call the library's cleanup function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, that's always one option. I am looking specifically for ways to avoid that.

Comment: @ikegami Technically there are no class destructors in Java. I can add a finalizer, which come with their own sets of issues. That's why I wanted to explore the options for a native solution first.

Comment: I'm aware of they are called finalizers, and that they aren't timely. Neither of which aren't problems. Just explicitly release the resources in normal circumstances, and let the destructor handle the exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about JNI, but I guess your shared library is just loaded at some point, using `dlopen` or the likes in windows.
gcc and clang have `__attribute__((destructor))` (and `constructor`).
You can use this for cleanup and initialization.
On windows, you could use the `DllMain` and check for the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` or `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` reasons.
It should be called after the last `dlclose` is called for your library.
Don't use printouts to debug it, as at this time, the `stdout` may already be closed.

```
__attribute__((destructor)) void myCleanupFn(){
    // Cleanup :-)
}
```

Comment: `__attribute__((destructor))` looks good (the library is Linux-only). I assume this is called after all threads have already been terminated? Is this specified somewhere?

Comment: It's a gcc attribute, but also supported by clang - see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html  
Doc says it's called after main, but I checked and it works with a shared library as well, it is called after the dlclose.